# Blank M.2 drive undetectable in both BIOS and ubuntu live

Tags: boot, bios, ubuntu-16.04, nvme

Been having an absolute nightmare with Clonezilla, thing keeps crashing mid clone and corrupting my drive's superblocks AND all backup superblocks. Anyways, so I deleted all partitions off of my M.2 NVME HP500gb drive and now it's completely undetectable in both the BIOS and ubuntu live. It's undetectable in both slots 2 and 3 (1 is hidden under gpu card), regardless of additional SATA drives being connected to the SATA ports.

At the same time my Inland Basic 256gb Nvme drive is detected in either M.2 slots 2 or 3 and is booting fine. There maybe an issue with the UUID of both M.2's being the same due to clonezilla fails, but the HP M.2 drive wont work with or without the Inland. There's no settings in the BIOS blocking M.2 lanes or PCIEx4 lanes, SATA is set to ACHI, nvme is not in raid config - I have tried every combination of these settings.

This happened a month ago and I 'fixed' it by flashing the BIOS to latest version. I tried this again to no success.

The mobo in question is a Gigabyte Asorus X399 Xtreme. Thanks!

Edit: to clarify above, I am NOT using ANY SATA ports. Also I don't have a spare mobo with M.2 ports lying around

Comment: Have you tried the M.2 drive in another machine?  Have you tried a new M.2 drive with all of your other actions the same, on your original machine?

Comment: SATA drives shouldn't have anything to do with an NVMe drive not being detected unless you are using a SATA port that would normally be disabled when you used the shared bandwidth from the M.2 slot.  What SATA ports are you using?  Edit your question in order to provide this necessary information.

Comment: Again, I have a second M.2 drive that works fine, and no spare mobo. Also again, no SATA ports are in use.